# In Rust, is it possible to accept arbitrary syntax in attribute macros? (just like other macros)

Tags: rust, macros, attributes

In Rust, both declarative and procedural macros (`macro_rules!`) can accept arbitrary syntax which isn't necessarily valid Rust, provided that it parses. For instance, [in the docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-06-macros.html#function-like-macros), this is used to create a macro which parses SQL queries from an SQL-like syntax.

However, when using attribute macros, this does not seem to be the case. For example:

```
#[my_attribute_macro]
fn example() {
    impl A {
        impl B {
            // This is invalid Rust code (nested `impl`s) which is parsable
        }
    }
}
```

Yields a compiler error because `impl`s cannot be nested in valid Rust. Is there any way of working around this limitation, to get attribute macros which work more like other macros?

Comment: It's probably not possible. The attribute syntax needs to parse the function (or struct or whatever) below it so that it knows when the item it's affecting ends.

Comment: Well, that makes sense. That being said, the same restriction also applies to function-like macros, which also need to determine when the call ends, so I'm not sure where the difference lies.

Comment: Function-like macros just have to parse everything within the brackets, which is easier (similar to `{ $($tree:tt)* }`). Attributes probably just reuse the function parsing code, which parses statements in the body. The compiler could theoretically make an alternate function parser that parses a function while doing a similar thing to the above for the body, but it likely hasn't been done yet.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is not possible today.
The example you see in the docs is a function-like macro, not an attribute macro (proc-macro).

You can provide custom syntax to macros like this:
sql!( CUSTOM SYNTAX )

But not to macros like this:
#[sql]
fn sql() {
Custom Syntax
}